# What do the generic type constraints ":<:" and ":+:" mean in this Scala example?

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-cats, higher-kinded-types, recursion-schemes

From this talk about nanopass compilers in 2017 (https://github.com/sellout/recursion-scheme-talk/blob/master/nanopass-compiler-talk.org) I found the code snippet below. In this code snipped, I see two generic constraints that I have searched high and low to understand but have not been able to find any information about them. What I'm hoping to understand is:

- What are these operators doing?
- Where did they come from?
- Is there a more modern equivalent in the latest versions of Scala and related libraries?

```scala
final case class Let[A](bindings: List[(String, A)], body: A)
final case class If[A](test: A, consequent: A, alt: A)

def expandLet[Lambda :<: F]: Fix[Let :+: F] => Fix[F] =
  _.unFix match {
    case Let(bindings, body) =>
      bindings.unzip((names, exprs) =>
        Fix(App(Fix(Lam(names, expandLet(body)).inject),
                exprs.map(expandLet)).inject))
    // and don’t forget the other cases
  }

def expandIf[Lambda :<: F]: Fix[If :+: F] => Fix[F] =
  _.unFix match {
    case If(test, consequent, alt) =>
      Fix(App(expandIf(test), List(
        Fix(Lam(Nil, expandIf(consequent))),
        Fix(Lam(Nil, expandIf(alt))))))
    // seriously, still gotta handle the other cases
  }
```

Comment: There is email of the talk author at that page (Greg Pfeil greg@slamdata.com greg@technomadic.org https://twitter.com/sellout). Why wouldn't you ask them? :)

Comment: Probably some compiler plugin because this is not valid Scala syntax

Comment: `:+:` looks like a coproduct for type constructors: `type :+:[A[_], B[_]] = t =>> A[t] | B[t]` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/MQvitQbsT5qr5lwgIuIK7g/1 (Scala 3)

Comment: https://github.com/precog/matryoshka seems not being updated

Comment: I looked into it, slamdata doesn't appear to be alive anymore? Shame, it was based in my home town and doing interesting work, I might have applied if I moved back. Either way, after so many years I didn't want to bother him about something so old. I wasn't expecting an answer so quickly and directly from him. Thanks, greg!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My apologies … I borrowed some Haskell-y “type operators” to make things fit better on the slides for the talk, but I think it just caused more confusion.

`F :+: G` would be something like `Coproduct[F, G, ?]` where `type Coproduct[F, G, A] = Either[F[A], G[A]]`. I.e., it allows you to compose pattern functors, to build a richer language out of smaller pieces.

`F :<: G` is a bit more complicated. It would be something like `Contains[F, G]`, where

```
trait Contains[F, G] {
  def inject[A](in: F[A]): G[A]
  def project[A](outOf: G[A]): Option[F[A]]
}

val theSame[F] = new Contains[F, F] {
    def inject[A](in: F[A]) = in
    def project[A](outOf: F[A]) = Some(outOf)
}

val onTheLeft[F, G] = new Contains[F, Coproduct[F, G]] {
    def inject[A](in: F[A]) = Left(in)
    def project[A](outOf: Coproduct[F, G]) = outOf match {
        case Left(in) => Some(in)
        case Right(_) => None
    }
}

val nested[F, G, H](implicit further: Contains[F, H]) =
    new Contains[F, Coproduct[G, H]] {
        def inject[A](in: F[A]) = Right(further.inject(in))
        def project[A](outOf: Coproduct[G, H]) = outOf match {
            case Left(_) => None
            case Right(h) => further.project(h)
        }
    }
```

So a better version of this code (although still not valid – I haven’t written Scala a few years) is

```
def expandLet[F](input: Fix[Coproduct[Let, F]])
                (implicit contains: Contains[Lambda, F])
    : Fix[F] =
  input.unFix match {
    case Left(Let(bindings, body)) =>
      bindings.unzip((names, exprs) =>
        Fix(App(Fix(Lam(names, expandLet(body)).inject),
                exprs.map(expandLet)).inject))
    // and don’t forget the other cases
  }
```

I still use this technique, just not in Scala, and they way I use it has changed a bit (e.g., I would make `expandLet` an algebra, to eliminate the recursive calls). But the concepts in that talk are still relevant, at least.

If you want to write code like this in Scala, I think [Droste](https://github.com/higherkindness/droste) is the way to go these days.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry for pinging you, just in case.

Comment: You rock, Greg. I absolutely love this stuff but my immediate peers have no interest in functional programming, type-level stuff, or anything with weird words. I've been studying it on my own for the past two years and can't get enough.